# jQuery Autocomplete doesn't load more than 250 MySQL records?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete, fetch

I have a form of product where product name fild has an autocomplete feature but it doesn't load more than 250 records. If I put the limit to 300 or 500 then it doesn't work. Below is my code, can anybody tell me if there is any issue in my script.

```
           jQuery.noConflict();
            jQuery(function() {
                var availableTags = [
                    <?php
                    $query_product = "SELECT DISTINCT prod_name FROM tbl_product LIMIT 250";
                    $result_product = mysql_query($query_product);
                    while($row_product = mysql_fetch_array($result_product))
                    {
                    $prod_name = $row_product['prod_name'];
                    ?>
                    "<?php echo $prod_name; ?>",
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                ];
                jQuery('input[name="item[]"]').autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags
                });
            });



<input type="text" placeholder="Item" id="item" name="item[]">
```

Comment: `If I put the limit to 300 or 500 then it doesn't work`, can you explain `doesn't work`? No results, error, etc.

Comment: @chris85 If I remove limit from my query or put some thing like 300 or 350 in limit then it doesn't load anything in my autocomplete.

Comment: Does it throw an error, are you checking for errors?

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all, `?>
                    "<?php echo $prod_name; ?>",
                    <?php`?

Comment: @chris85 I'm trying to find a way to echo query but don't know as I'm a beginner in php. I replace  `"<?php echo $prod_name; ?>"`, with  `"<?php echo $query_product; ?>"`, but it just echo query 250 times in item field

Comment: @jeroen That's just the SO syntax highlighter not being able to make heads or tails of the code. It should execute without a problem tbh, albeit the code is ugly.

Comment: You'd use `echo $query_product;`, before the `while`, or even `die($query_product);` since you are debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that one of your `$row_product['prod_name']` has a single-quote or backslash in it so your database data needs to be sanitized before giving it to Javascript.

I think your code needs to look like this:

```
var availableTags = [
    <?php
    $query_product = "SELECT DISTINCT prod_name FROM tbl_product LIMIT 250";
    $result_product = mysql_query($query_product);
    while($row_product = mysql_fetch_array($result_product))
    {
        echo "'".str_replace("'", "\\'", str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $row_product['prod_name']))."',";
    }
    ?>
];
```

Comment: I don't think manually generating a javascript array in php is a very good idea :-)

Comment: it's working now and i think there was double quotes or single quotes in some products name that's why it make an issue. how can we skip `&` sign as some product has `&` in the name and the code doesn't process that.

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT DISTINCT prod_name FROM tbl_product LIMIT 250";
```

try removing the LIMIT 250 part?

Comment: if I remove LIMIT or put LIMIT greater than 250 then the autocomplete doesn't work at all. It doesn't load anything then.

Comment: OP states tried with higher values, `If I put the limit to 300 or 500 then it doesn't work`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess as there is not enough information to go on, but this looks very wrong:

```
var availableTags = [
    <?php
    ...
    ?>
    "<?php echo $prod_name; ?>",
    <?php
    ...
    ?>
    ];
```

It looks like you are trying to build json / a javascript array but what you are outputting is probably not what you need and any special character in your data would break the json. So my guess is that around product 250 there is a product that breaks your results.

What you should do, is build an array and use `json_encode()` to send that directly to javascript:

```
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($your_array); ?>;
```

Comment: I would say this would be the **most** fool-proof option. `var availableTags = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($your_array); ?>');` ;-)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No, when you `echo json_encode(...)` you already have a javascript object or array. You cannot parse that as json as it is not a string.